# How "much" emissions or how "many" emissions?

Tags: grammatical-number, word-usage, be

The following is what I found in the website of US Energy Information Administration. 
Is the word "emissions" usually used with "much" as in the quotation? If so, why is the verb "are" used instead of "is?"

How much of U.S. carbon dioxide emissions are associated with electricity generation?

Comment: I don't think emission is a count-noun.

Comment: Personally, I would rewrite the sentence. But if stuck with it, I'd go with *is* here as an improvement. It suggests you are looking for a percentage of the total. If you really want the tonnage of the emissions tied to electricity generation, it needs to be rewritten.

Comment: @RamPillai It is always a count noun, but it has some weird habits. The problem here is that the causal agent is plural (power plants and associated industries), but it never actually appears in the sentence. So we have this disjoint between the noncount *electricity generation* and the machines that produce the emissions.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @PhilSweet

Comment: Actually, you could make the argument it isn't the electricity generation that needs to be plural, just that electricity generation is one of bunch of  source categories. In that case, *is* pretty much fixes the issue, but it is still a confusing sentence.

Comment: @Phil Sweet Certainly, as Lexico and other dictionaries say, 'emission' is non-count in one subsense. However, the plural-form 'emissions'  resists numeral insertion (?/??'The three emissions from the refinery were disastrous', and I'm leaning towards a 'plural-form non-count' usage here.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is with *emission*. It has pretty much always been both a count and non-count noun (see [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/emission) for examples), but some jiggery pokery has occurred to make the plural non-count too.

When talking about a gas or other thing that can be emitted, "an emission of" is a quantifier for a non-count thing. Like "a slice of cake" or "a bottle of milk", "an emission of CO<sub>2</sub>" is quite obviously grammatical.

It can also be a container for count things, like "a bag of apples", for example: "an emission of rays".

Then in a non-count way "CO<sub>2</sub> emission is causing global warming", seems perfectly normal too.

The normal use of the plural is in the count situation: "The millions of beta-particle emissions per seconds are degrading the container quite quickly."

For some reason, a quirk of English I can't account for, *emissions* can be treated as simultaneously count and non-count. Here are some examples:

- > how much emissions are achieved in different locations — [Energy Systems Engineering: Evaluation and Implementation](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Fet1UJ9XOcIC&q=%22how+much+emissions+are%22&dq=%22how+much+emissions+are%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwic9Leg7fHmAhXdRxUIHYn5AOI4ChDoAQgvMAE)
- > knowing just how much emissions are actually produced by aircraft engines. — [Aeroengines and propulsion: selected papers from Aerotech 95](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CIJTAAAAMAAJ&q=%22how+much+emissions+are%22&dq=%22how+much+emissions+are%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwic9Leg7fHmAhXdRxUIHYn5AOI4ChDoAQgoMAA)
- > How much emissions are produced in both sourcing and creating the materials?  — [Designing for Sustainability](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=w5PkDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT41&dq=%22how+much+emissions+are%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikhtzn7vHmAhV1tXEKHa82AckQ6AEIMTAB)

This usage seems pretty recent, but perhaps I'm searching for the wrong thing. Maybe this marks *emissions* as in a transitory period toward full non-count status?

Google books doesn't have any hits for "how much emissions is", but searching the wider web throws up a few examples:

- > [How much of China's CO2 emissions is made to produce goods for the U.S. or Europe?](https://www.reddit.com/r/environment/comments/czy4kn/how_much_of_chinas_co2_emissions_is_made_to/)
- > [If we're sure how much emissions is the right amount](https://tierneylab.blogs.nytimes.com/2007/05/26/which-carbon-diet-works-better/#comment-3564)
- > [the argument about how much emissions is avoided](https://bravenewclimate.com/2011/05/21/co2-avoidance-cost-wind/) (by Wookey, @ 31 May 2011 at 5:35 AM)

And yes, these are obviously all colloquial and not formal, and it doesn't happen enough yet to be recorded in a dictionary, but it looks like it's on its way.

So in answer to your question: it's unusual to use *emissions* that way, but that use is growing in popularity, so can't be completely discounted as ungrammatical.

Comment: This rings true. I'd come to the same conclusions before just now reading this. But I'd go with 'What proportion of U.S. carbon dioxide emissions is associated with electricity generation?' / '... if we're sure what tonnage of emissions is the acceptable amount'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The use in the question certainly seems odd to me. Rewording makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky.
How much of CO2 emissions
Meaning how much CO2 (in those emissions)
This leaves "emissions" as the subject of the sentence. Hence, "are, etc."
It's not CO2 that's associated with electricity generation, it's the emission of it.
(I may be wrong. Don't hesitate to correct me if I am.)

Answer (score 0):

I regard the "are" as an error.

The subject of this sentence is the singular combined volume of those plural sources.  The plural noun "emissions" is embedded in a prepositional phrase, so it shouldn't directly affect subject/verb agreement.

> How much [of U.S. carbon dioxide emissions] is associated with electricity generation?

With or without the prepositional phrase, scholastic English expects "how much" to agree with "is".  Whether expressed as an absolute mass or a relative proportion, the expected answer to this question is just one thing.

Although it's an error, it's a very easy mistake to make.  There is a plural word as a part of the complete subject.  That word immediately precedes the verb which needs to agree with something.  "Emissions are" is the easiest point of agreement to find, even though it isn't the most sensible.

The word "much" does not pair directly with the countable sense of "emissions".  Here, the connection is bridged by the preposition "of".  The phrasing of "how much of [these plural things]" follows a common and unremarkable pattern.  Also common and unremarkable are the patterns of the phrasings "how much emission" (in the uncountable sense) and "how many emissions" (in the countable).